# Gremlin: Build the output of the query as a 2D array

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, gremlin-server

I want to get the list of friends of all the users of the graph in a 2D array fornat like:

```
[
  [friend, friend, friend],
  [friend, friend, friend],
  [friend, friend, friend],
]
```

I've came up with this query:
`g.V().hasLabel("user").both("friend");`

But that query returns the friends of all the users and puts it in to the same list, not what I want, I want a 2D array where each item is the list of friends for each user.

What do I need to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Self response:**
bechbd response is correct but a more simple and readable solution is to use `flatMap()` like this:
`g.hasLabel("user").flatMap(both("friend").fold())`

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this thorough the use of [project()](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#project-step), [select()](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#select-step), as well as [fold()](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#fold-step)/[unfold()](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#unfold-step) steps to format the results of your traversal in the desired fashion.  For example if I run the traversal below on the modern graph in TinkerPop:

```
g.V().project('foff').
    by(
        both().fold().
        project('foff').
        by(
            unfold().both().fold()
        )
    ).
    select(values).unfold().
    select(values).fold()
```

I get a 2D array of answers like this:

```
[
  [[v[1],v[4],v[6],v[1],v[5],v[3],v[1]]],
  [[v[3],v[2],v[4]]],
  [[v[3],v[2],v[4],v[5],v[3],v[1],v[3]]],
  [[v[4],v[1],v[4],v[6],v[3],v[2],v[4]]],
  [[v[5],v[3],v[1]]],[[v[1],v[4],v[6]]]
]
```

Comment: Your solution applied to the code of my question is more simple and looks like this:
`g.V().hasLabel('user').project('f').by(both("friend").fold()).unfold().select(values).dedup();` And it works, thanks!